# How do I replace a map in a Wikipedia infobox?

Tags: wikipedia

The German-language Wikipedia page [Oblast Donezk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblast_Donezk) has an infobox, shown below.

How can I replace the map? The infobox does not have an entry for the map .svg-file.

```
{{Infobox Oblast Ukraine
|Oblast = Oblast Donezk
|область = Донецька область/''Donezka oblast''<br />Донецкая область/''Donezkaja oblast''
|Wappen = Coat of Arms of Donetsk Oblast 1999.svg
|Flagge = Flag of Donetsk Oblast.svg
|Hauptstadt = Donezk
|Sprachen = [[Ukrainische Sprache|Ukrainisch]], [[Russische Sprache|Russisch]]
|Einwohner = 4100280
|EW_Stand = 2021
|inStädten = 90,1
|Fläche = 26517
|KOATUU = 1400000000
|KATOTTH = UA14000000000091971
|Kfz=AH, KH
|Rajon = 8
|StädteO = 28
|StädteR = 24
|Stadtbezirke = 21
|SsT = 131
|Dörfer = 1115
|Siedlungen = 244
|Adresse = бульвар Пушкіна 34<br />83105 м. Донецьк
|Website = http://www.donoda.gov.ua/
|StatLink = 6942
|}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Infobox Oblast Ukraine" template on the German Wikipedia determines the map based on the Oblast parameter. The article says:

```
{{Infobox Oblast Ukraine
|Oblast = Oblast Donezk
...
}}
```

This eventually makes its way to, in the template:

```
{{Imagemap Ukraine1|{{#switch: {{{Oblast|}}}
 | #default = Ukraine adm location map.svg
        | Oblast Charkiw = Kharkiv in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Cherson = Kherson in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Chmelnyzkyj = Khmelnytskyi in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Tscherniwzi = Chernivtsi in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Dnipropetrowsk = Dnipropetrovsk in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Donezk = Donetsk in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Iwano-Frankiwsk = Ivano-Frankivsk in Ukraine.svg
        | Kiew = Kiev (city) in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Kiew = Kiev (oblast) in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Kirowohrad = Kirovohrad in Ukraine.svg
        | Krim = Crimea in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Lwiw = Lviv in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Luhansk = Luhansk in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Mykolajiw = Mykolaiv in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Odessa = Odessa in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Poltawa = Poltava in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Riwne = Rivne in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Saporischschja = Zaporizhia in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Schytomyr = Zhytomyr in Ukraine.svg
        | Stadt Sewastopol = Sevastopol in Ukraine.svg
        | Sewastopol = Sevastopol in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Sumy = Sumy in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Ternopil = Ternopil in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Transkarpatien = Zakarpattia in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Tscherkassy = Cherkasy in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Tschernihiw = Chernihiv in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Winnyzja = Vinnytsia in Ukraine.svg
        | Oblast Wolyn = Volyn in Ukraine.svg}}|299px}}
```

`{{{Oblast|}}}` refers to the value passed as `|Oblast=` above (`Oblast Donezk`), and that giant switch statement turns it into `Donetsk in Ukraine.svg` `{{Imagemap Ukraine1|...}}` then modifies the map (via a set of hardcoded pixel positions) so you can click on each oblast to go to that article. This process is not practical to change.

Comment: great answer! actually, in this case, it might be more sensible to change the default map.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this template. It is an infobox for a country in German Wikipedia.
Your example is the infobox for a Ukrainian oblast, it might have very similar structure.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorlage:Infobox_Staat

There are six entries related to 'map'.

```
|BILD-LAGE          = 
|BILD-LAGE-BESCHREIBUNG = 
|BILD1              = weltkarte.jpg
|BILD1-BESCHREIBUNG = Karte 1
|BILD2              = weltkarte.jpg
|BILD2-BESCHREIBUNG = Karte 2
```

which translates to

```
|IMAGE-POSITION =
|PICTURE-LOCATION-DESCRIPTION =
|BILD1 = world map.jpg
|PICTURE1 DESCRIPTION = Card 1
|BILD2 = world map.jpg
|PICTURE2 DESCRIPTION = Card 2
```

You may use this entries.

EDIT:

There is a German Wikipedia template for Ukrainian Oblast.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorlage:Infobox_Oblast_Ukraine

It seems that there is no entry for a map so that a user can insert an image.

Comment: A interesting and logical suggestion - I have tried with many different names like BILD-LAGE or BILD1, but it has no effect on the map.

Comment: It appears that there is a function behind, which is reading  the field  `|Oblast` and outputs the map. So, if I change `|Oblast`, let's say, to `Oblast Kiew`, it will produce the map highlighting the Kyiv Oblast. But how to access this function (or whatever it is) remains unclear...